# XSLT-1.0: Create multiple records when child node has multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Create multiple records when child has multiple values.

I have an XML with parent and child nodes. Child nodes do have multiple values. I am trying to create separate records for each child nodes such that the tags are in the order displayed in the output (Desired).

My XML input is:

```
<Records count="65">
  <Record contentId="781435" levelId="17" levelGuid="33fceb92-9ee6-458f-81f6-5bd28e4af22e" moduleId="70" parentId="0">
    <Field id="15941" guid="75b528ad-2e19-42d6-9512-87b92bbf84d0" type="1">SPH0</Field>
    <Field id="15997" guid="90507e16-35a1-407e-8b27-586e3e091ac3" type="9">
      <Reference id="409826">Alberta</Reference>
    </Field>
  </Record>
  <Record contentId="783299" levelId="17" levelGuid="33fceb92-9ee6-458f-81f6-5bd28e4af22e" moduleId="70" parentId="0">
    <Field id="15941" guid="75b528ad-2e19-42d6-9512-87b92bbf84d0" type="1">SQV0</Field>
    <Field id="15997" guid="90507e16-35a1-407e-8b27-586e3e091ac3" type="9">
      <Reference id="409187">Ontario</Reference>
      <Reference id="409826">Quebec</Reference>
    </Field>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

My XSLT code which I tried is:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Records">
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
            <ArcherRecord>
                <AppCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Field" />
                </AppCode>
                <xsl:for-each select="Field/Reference">
                    <Location>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </Location>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ArcherRecord>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output I got is:

```
<ArcherRecord>
    <AppCode>SPH0</AppCode>
    <Location>Alberta</Location>
</ArcherRecord>

<ArcherRecord>
    <AppCode>SQV0</AppCode>
    <Location>Ontario</Location>
    <Location>Quebec</Location>
</ArcherRecord>
```

instead of the output I desire which would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArcherRecord>
    <AppCode>SPH0</AppCode>
    <Location>Alberta</Location>
</ArcherRecord>

<ArcherRecord>
    <AppCode>SQV0</AppCode>
    <Location>Ontario</Location>
</ArcherRecord>

<ArcherRecord>
    <AppCode>SQV0</AppCode>
    <Location>Quebec</Location>
</ArcherRecord>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Records">
        <xsl:for-each select="Record/Field/Reference">
            <ArcherRecord>
                <AppCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../Field[@type='1']" />
                </AppCode>                    
                    <Location>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </Location>                    
            </ArcherRecord>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<ArcherRecord>
   <AppCode>SPH0</AppCode>
   <Location>Alberta</Location>
</ArcherRecord>
<ArcherRecord>
   <AppCode>SQV0</AppCode>
   <Location>Ontario</Location>
</ArcherRecord>
<ArcherRecord>
   <AppCode>SQV0</AppCode>
   <Location>Quebec</Location>
</ArcherRecord>
```

Comment: Thanks  Pavan..This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: How does accepting an answer work? for more information.